# Unit Testing & System.Web.Routing

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-routing

I have a test project and am trying to reference System.Web.Routing. I've added the reference to the project but I am getting the error:

```
The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

I'm sure there is a logical reason for this but I do not know what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed a reference to System.Web. Thought I had that already referenced...oops!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add this reference too

[image: You need to add this reference too]

Comment: Thanks @matiasnj! I realized that right after I posted my question and posted an answer.

Comment: No problem, I saw this and as I was posting you first realise, good luck!